# Asp.net MVC trying to let the user add multiple details such as multiple emails to a contact

Tags: c#, css, mysql, asp.net, model-view-controller

Im working on a project that serves as a contact book where users can add edit delete contacts that have a few details such as email,first name, last name, phone number etc. Im trying to make it possible for a user to add multiple emails to a contact.

How would i go about doing this? At the moment im using one contact model linked with a sql database table whit all the contact variables. Would i have to create another table for emails and pair it with the contact table?

```
model
namespace test1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Contact
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> phonenr { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    }
}

Controller

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using test1.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace test1.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]

    public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        private ContactBookEntities1 db = new ContactBookEntities1();

        // GET: Contact
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Contacts.ToList());
        }

        [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult Index(string Empsearch)
        {
            ViewData["Getcontactdetails"] = Empsearch;

            var conquery = from x in db.Contacts select x;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Empsearch))
            {
                conquery = conquery.Where(x => x.fname.Contains(Empsearch) || x.email.Contains(Empsearch)); 
            }
            return View(conquery.AsNoTracking().ToList());
        }


        
        public FileContentResult DownloadCSV()
        {
            string csv = "\"ID\",\"First Name\",\"Last Name\",\"Email\",\"Phone Number\",\"Adress\" \n";
            List<Contact> List = db.Contacts.ToList(); //get this list from database 
            foreach (Contact item in List)
            {
                csv = csv + String.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\",\"{5}\" \n",
                                           item.id,
                                           item.fname,
                                           item.lname,
                                           item.email,
                                           item.phonenr,
                                           item.address);
            }
            return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "Report123.csv");
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
        {
            string filePath = string.Empty;
            if (postedFile != null)
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                //Create a DataTable.
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[6] { 
                    new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)),
                    new DataColumn("First Name", typeof(string)),
                                new DataColumn("Last Name", typeof(string)),
                                new DataColumn("Email", typeof(string)),
                                new DataColumn("Phone Number", typeof(int)),
                                new DataColumn("Adress",typeof(string)) });


                //Read the contents of CSV file.
                string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

                //Execute a loop over the rows.
                foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add();
                        Contact contact = new Contact();
                        //Execute a loop over the columns.
                        var cell = row.Split(',');
                        contact.fname = cell[1];
                        contact.lname = cell[2];
                        contact.email=  cell[3];
                        contact.phonenr =Convert.ToInt32(cell[4]);
                        contact.address= cell[5];

                        db.Contacts.Add(contact);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        //foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                        //{
                            
                        

                        //    //dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                        //    i++;
                        //}
                    }
                }

                
            }
            var model = db.Contacts.ToList();
            return View(model);
        }



        [Authorize(Roles = "guest, superadmin")]
        // GET: Contact/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
            if (contact == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contact);
        }



        // GET: Contact/Create

        
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Contact/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]


        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,fname,lname,email,phonenr,address")] Contact contact)
        {
            //HttpPostedFileBase 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Contacts.Add(contact);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(contact);
        }

        // GET: Contact/Edit/5
        [Authorize(Roles = "admin, superadmin")]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
            if (contact == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contact);
        }

        // POST: Contact/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,fname,lname,email,phonenr,address")] Contact contact)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(contact);
        }

        // GET: Contact/Delete/5
        [Authorize(Roles = "admin, superadmin")]
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
            if (contact == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contact);
        }

        // POST: Contact/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
            db.Contacts.Remove(contact);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Create Contact view

Comment: The POST needs to send a List<Contact>in stead of just a Contact.  So your model needs a List<Contact>

Answer (score 0):

It's always the small changes that cause the biggest headaches. You can update your partial class "email" property to a list of string and yes you would create a foreign key from this persons contact to an "Emails" table to link them.

Just a heads up this is going to require you to revise your view to display emails as well. You'll need to loop through them instead of just display the one email it was expecting before.

```
   public partial class Contact
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string fname { get; set; }
            public string lname { get; set; }
            *public List<string> email { get; set; }*
            public Nullable<int> phonenr { get; set; }
            public string address { get; set; }
        }
```